# Create new arrays in a specific order with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i get arrays with elements of base array order like this with JS :

```
baseArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

newArray1 = [1,4,7]
newArray2 = [2,5,8]
newArray3 = [3,6]
```

What is the best way

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is exactly. Try to specify what exactly you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: So what did you try? This sounds like a "DO MY HOMEWORK FOR ME" type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the power of the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) for getting the right index and the target array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    array1 = [], array2 = [], array3 = [];

array.reduce((r, v, i) => (r[i % 3].push(v), r), [array1, array2, array3]);
    
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
console.log(array3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try either filtering

```
newArray1 = baseArray.filter(function(value, index, Arr) {
    return index % 3 == 0;
});

newArray2 = baseArray.filter(function(value, index, Arr) {
    return index % 3 == 1;
});

newArray3 = baseArray.filter(function(value, index, Arr) {
    return index % 3 == 2;
});
```

or directly accesing array elements

```
let newArray1 = [];
let newArray2 = [];
let newArray3 = [];

for (let i=0; i<baseArray.length; j++){
    if (i%3==0) newArray1.push(baseArray[i]);
    if (i%3==1) newArray2.push(baseArray[i]);
    if (i%3==2) newArray3.push(baseArray[i]);
}
```